# Problemas com upload de imagens em PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Eu nunca mexi com upload de ficheiros e hoje preciso mesmo de o fazer. Eu tenho um código para teste, para depois usá-lo no site.

Aqui tenho o **HTML**:

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="inserir.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>File: </label><input type="file" name="imagem" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

E aqui o **PHP**:

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "teste3");

    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagem'])); //SQL Injection defence!
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['imagem']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO testeimg (imagem) VALUES ({$imagem})";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo "<script>alert('Sucesso');</script>";
}
else{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Eu estive a pesquisar um pouco e foi nisto que deu, mas dá-me erro ao inserir na **BD**.

Alguém me pode ajudar nisto?

PS: Eu tenho uma database: `teste3`, tabela: `testeimg` com `id` `auto_increment PK` e `imagem` com `LONGBLOB`.

Comment: Não te aconselho a guardares imagens diretamente na BD. Devias ter as imagens em algum sitio e na BD só a *path* para a imagem.

Comment: Mas querendo guardar deves usar `$_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']` para gravar a imagem na BD.

Comment: @JorgeB. Obrigado pela sugestão! Podes-me indicar um sitio para aprender a fazer isso? É que eu não sei mesmo (agora sei um pouco mas continuo um nabo)

Comment: @JorgeB. Como eu indico para a imagem ir para uma pasta Upload

Comment: Podes ver o exemplo na minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não te aconselho a guardares imagens diretamente na BD. Devias ter as imagens em algum sitio e na BD só a *path* para a imagem.

Para fazeres isso basta usares a função [`move_uploaded_file`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
$image    = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
$img_name = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];

$dir      = "/caminho/para/a/pasta/";
$path     = $dir.$img_name;

move_uploaded_file( $image, $path );    

$sql = "INSERT INTO testeimg (imagem) VALUES ({$path})";
//não esquecer que imagem passa a ser um VARCHAR
```

Mas querendo guardar deves usar `$_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name']` para gravar a imagem na BD.

```
$image = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
$sql   = "INSERT INTO testeimg (imagem) VALUES ({$image})";
```

Tens aqui o manual oficial e tem também exemplos [Upload de arquivos com o método POST](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Comment: Se eu quiser meter numa pasta img na mesma pasta em  que está este ficheiro o que meto no $dir? img apenas?

Comment: `$dir = "img/";` ou `$dir = "./img/";`

Comment: E como faço para ir buscar? Desculpa estar a fazer tantas perguntas mas eu nunca mexi com upload files e sou um bocado nabo.. É só meter no src da img tipo uma variavel para ir buscar o path da db?

Comment: Depende, o que queres fazer com a imagem? Mostra-la na página ou fazer download dela?

Comment: Eu queria mostra-la. E se for com ficheiros é o mesmo processo?

Comment: Acho que era melhor fazeres uma pergunta com isso que é um bocado grande para comentários. Mas basicamente vais busca a path guardada na BD e usas no HTML `<img src="<?php echo "$dir/$img_name" ?>" >` ou tudo em PHP `echo " <img src='$dir/$img_name' >";`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25702/discussion-between-bruno-gibellino-and-jorge-b).

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim, deste modo você irá armazenar a imagem no BD:

```
$nomeFinal = time().'.jpg'; //nome final que será trocado com o temporario
//move e renomeia o arquivo (se conseguir mover é porque o arquivo enviado é valido)
if (move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'], $nomeFinal)) { 
    $tamanhoImg = filesize($nomeFinal); 
    $mysqlImg = addslashes(fread(fopen($nomeFinal, "r"), $tamanhoImg));
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "teste3");
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO teste (imgem) VALUES ('$mysqlImg')");
    unlink($nomeFinal);// apaga a imagem do diretorio porque ela já esta 
    //armazenada no BD
}
```

OBS: É aconselhável não armazenar arquivos no BD mas sim o endereço deles.

Answer (score 1):

Por algum motivo obscuro no meu servidor web eu necessito colocar [0] no tmp_name, pois me retorna um vetor, no seu caso talvez seja necessário remove-lo.

```
<?php
 $binario = file_get_contents($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]);
 $lenght = $_FILES['files']['size'][0];
 if($lenght > 0){

   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "teste3");
   $sql = "INSERT INTO testeimg (imagem) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($binario,$con) . "')";

   if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
      echo "<script>alert('Sucesso');</script>";
   }else{
      echo mysqli_connect_error();
   }
}else{
    echo "Erro no Upload!";
}
?>
```